# How to pass OnSelectRow value to controller's Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I need to pass the onselectRow value to controller's Action Method.In the following Example I need to pass **colData** value to **passval method** in Home Controller?How to do this?

Simply known as,How to pass **colData** value to **Passval Method** by using jqgrid's Url property

```
             onSelectRow: function () {
                    var rowId = $("#persontable").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    var rowData = jQuery("#persontable").getRowData(rowId);
                    var colData = rowData['HiddenFieldCandidateId'];

                    $("#persontable1").jqGrid({
                        url: '/Home/passval',
                        datatype: "json",
                        mtype: 'GET',
                        etc...

                    });
```

Action Method

```
            public string passval(string coldataval)
                 {
                   string val=coldataval;
                 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the Value Like,

```
url: '/Home/passval?data'+colData,
```

And get the value like,

```
public string passval(string coldataval)
                 {
                   string val=coldataval;
                 }
```